# Understanding shallow-reverse in clojure?

Tags: clojure, reverse

I am trying to learn clojure and I came across this snippet of code. Can anybody explain what exactly is happening?  The lines with a star in front are the ones that I need help understanding.  Thanks!

```
(defn shallow-reverse 
  "Reverses the top level elements of lst"
  *([lst] 
    (shallow-reverse () lst))
  *([reversed lst]
    (cond
      (empty? lst) reversed
      :else (recur (cons (first lst) reversed) (rest lst)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax defines a function `shallow-reverse` with two different implementations, separated by different parameter lists, or [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity). In this case, the first version calls the second version providing default parameter values. The second implementation does a recursive loop on itself to take the first element from `lst` and add it to the front of `reversed`, and ending when there are no more elements in `lst`.

The [`recur`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/recur) call is an optimization that calls the current function, or [`loop`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/loop) if it exists, without using extra stack frames.

In other languages, you would define two separate functions, with the same name.

```
//Note: Pseudo code, not valid Java

public List<int> shallowReverse(List<int> lst) {
  return shallowReverse(new List<int>(), lst);
}

public List<int> shallowReverse(List<int> reversed, List<int> lst) {
  if(lst.size() < 1) return reversed;
  return shallowReverse(...);
}
```

For more information, take a look at the documentation on the [fn special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#fn).

Answer (score 0):

`cons` on a list places an element at the front. `first` takes the element off the front.

You could picture what happens in that code as having two piles of plates - one starts out empty. you take the top off one, and put it on top of the other. You repeat until there is only one pile. Now the element that was on the top is now on the bottom, and visa versa, with the ordering reversed.